# "Access is denied." for xp_cmdshell for network share

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, xp-cmdshell

On a SQL 2014 SP 1 instance a SQL Agent job  I'm using xp_cmdshell to return a list of files from a network share. This has recently stopped working and returns "Access is denied."

The command is `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR "\\backups\marshall\master" /A:-D /S /B'`

The command will work for a local folder.`EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR "C:\Temp" /A:-D /S /B'`

Running `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami'` returns the Windows account that is used for the SQL Engine and SQL Agent. This account has Full Control for the backup folder. I've deleted and re-added permissions for this account. I can manually add and delete files from this folder.

I will be changing the process to no longer use xp_cmdshell, but can't do that today. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed **both** the file-system security and the share-level security allow access to the SQL Server service account?

Comment: any additional security software added, better filtering, or a layer 7 firewall in between per chance?

Comment: No additional security or firewall in place. The SQL Server service account can write/delete backup (.bak and .trn) files via maintenance plan.

Comment: this likely sounds stupid, but have you tried running SSMS "As Administrator"

Comment: Yes, I've ran SSMS as the SQL Server service account, as Administrator and the combo of those two. Same results.

Comment: Is SQL Server and SQL Agent configured using same domain account?

Comment: Yes, the same account is used for the engine and the agent.

Comment: Is your SQL agent job running with non sa account? Also, are you able to run the exact command in SSMS using your account?

Comment: The SQL Agent account is in the sysadmin role. I get the same result when I run the command in SSMS with a sysadmin account.

Answer (score -1):

Create a proxy account to run xp_cmdshell and give the proxy access to your share.

[Link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2143/creating-a-sql-server-proxy-account-to-run-xpcmdshell/)

Comment: I think this answer could do with some more detail. Creating a proxy account could open a large security hole depending on the Windows account chosen.